# Setting up SublimeCodeIntel plugin to work with Rails/Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I have spent the last 30 minutes trying to find examples on how to configure `SublimeCodeIntel` plugin on Sublime Text 2 to work with Rails / Ruby on windows. And even if it is stated in the documentation that it does support Rails, there is no example of the configuration.

From what I've read so far, getting Rubygems to work with this plugin is not possible, but rails should work. Has anybody successfully set up this plugin and if so, can you please help or share your configuration with me?

Comment: https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/248

Comment: http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/ has installation guide. What things after these instructions don't work and which things work?

Comment: @mico well you get install guide which is basic specially if you use `package control` but there is not guide on how to setup this for windows, since sublimecodeintell has config file which you need to tune to have go to definition working.

Comment: This plugin does need a detailed usage documentation!! I have installed it long time and never happened to use it as its not st. forwardly documented.

Comment: @uDaY does go to defintion work for you? Are you using Windows?

Comment: If you change mind, You can use, netbeans with lots of supported plugins....

Comment: Use `Sublime Text 3` go to defintion works out of the box, but still no go to gem definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would say most people either use VS Code these days for Go To Definition in Ruby [Navigate to Ruby function definition in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658665/navigate-to-ruby-function-definition-in-vs-code)

Or RubyMine https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#lens_mode_code